# How to select specific labels in pytorch MNIST dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create dataloaders using only a specific digit from PyTorch Mnist dataset

I already tried to create my own Sampler but it doesn't work and I'm not sure I'm using correctly the mask.

```
class YourSampler(torch.utils.data.sampler.Sampler):

    def __init__(self, mask):

        self.mask = mask


    def __iter__(self):

        return (self.indices[i] for i in torch.nonzero(self.mask))


    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.mask)


mnist = datasets.MNIST(root=dataroot, train=True, download=True, transform = transform)   

mask = [True if mnist[i][1] == 5 else False for i in range(len(mnist))]

mask = torch.tensor(mask)   

sampler = YourSampler(mask)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist, batch_size=4, sampler = sampler, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
```

So far I had many different types of errors. For this implementation, it's "Stop Iteration".
I feel like this is very easy/stupid but I can't find a simple way to do it.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `StopIteration` is raised when your iterator is exhausted. Are you sure your mask is working correctly. You should also give the stacktrace to know what the problem is and provide your training loop.

Comment: `self.indices` is not defined in your `__iter__` method. What is it supposed to be? please add it to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help.
After a while I figured out a solution (but might not be the best at all):

```
class YourSampler(torch.utils.data.sampler.Sampler):
    def __init__(self, mask, data_source):
        self.mask = mask
        self.data_source = data_source

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([i.item() for i in torch.nonzero(mask)])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_source)

mnist = datasets.MNIST(root=dataroot, train=True, download=True, transform = transform)    
mask = [1 if mnist[i][1] == 5 else 0 for i in range(len(mnist))]
mask = torch.tensor(mask)   
sampler = YourSampler(mask, mnist)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist, batch_size=batch_size,sampler = sampler, shuffle=False, num_workers=workers)
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest option I can think of is to reduce the data set in-place:

```
indices = dataset.targets == 5 # if you want to keep images with the label 5
dataset.data, dataset.targets = dataset.data[indices], dataset.targets[indices]
```

Comment: how can this be fit into cases, where I multiple targets, say [5, 6, 7] has to be retrieved?

Comment: `indices = (dataset.targets == 5) | (dataset.targets == 6) | (dataset.targets == 7)` should do it

Comment: Hi, I got an empty dataset after doing this step in CIFAR10, are you sure your method is correct?

Comment: `indices = (dataset.targets == 0) | (dataset.targets == 1)` get `indices` is `False`

Comment: `>>> type(dataset.targets)
<class 'list'>` there may be some problems with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) as following:

```py
# For labels 5, 6 and 7
labels = [5, 6, 7]
indices = [idx for idx, target in enumerate(dataset.targets) if target in labels]
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Subset(dataset, indices),
                                         batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`StopIteration` is raised when your iterator is exhausted. Are you sure your mask is working correctly? it seems like you pass list of boolean values, yet torch.nonzero would expect floats or ints.

You should write:

`mask = [1 if mnist[i][1] == 5 else 0 for i in range(len(mnist))]`

You should also need to pass the dataset to your sampler such as:

`sampler = YourSampler(dataset, mask=mask)`

with this class definition

```
class YourSampler(torch.utils.data.sampler.Sampler):

    def __init__(self, dataset, mask):

        self.mask = mask
        self.dataset = dataset
...
```

For more details, you can refer to pytorch documentation(which shows the source code) to see how they implemented more advanced samplers:https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#SequentialSampler